# Makefile - get directory of itself from within included file

Tags: makefile

Say a makefile includes multiple other makefiles. How can these included makefiles get to know the path to themselves relative to the main makefile?

An example structure is as follows:

**main make**:

```
include ../dir1/dir2/make1.mk
include dir3/dir4/dir5/make2.mk

.PHONY: print_paths
print_paths:
    @echo $(dir1) && @echo $(dir2)
```

**make1**

```
dir1 = <some code>
```

**make2**

```
dir2 = <some code>
```

My expected output would be:

```
../dir1/dir2
dir3/dir4/dir5
```

I was able to solve this for a single include file through:

```
dir1 = $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

However, this does not seem to work for multiple files, as both `dir1` and `dir2` will be set equal to the directory of makefile two. (which is fair I guess? It is the last file included after all)

Alternatively them getting to know their absolute path would be fine as well.

Comment: Why not simply examine `$CURDIR`?

Comment: $(CURDIR) will return the path to the main makefile. I am looking for the relative path between the main makefile and the included makefiles.

Comment: More correctly, `$CURDIR` refers to the user's current directory. Retitled to hopefully make the question clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add:

```
dir1 := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

at the beginning of `../dir1/dir2/make1.mk` and:

```
dir2 := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

at the beginning of `dir3/dir4/dir5/make2.mk`.